# Setting up JavaScript testing with Minitest

Tags: integration, minitest

I have installed minitest, and in my integration folder I run the following code:

```
describe "some description" do
  it "should do something" do  
  end
end
```

it works. But if I want to implement js as following, it throws an error:

```
describe "as a student I want a working blog so people can post" do
  it "should do something", js: true do
  end
end
```

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

Thanks

Comment: Neither the describe clock accepts the js: true option

Comment: a little information: my test_helper.rb contains the following: require "minitest/autorun"
require "minitest/metadata"
require "minitest/rails"
require "minitest/rails/capybara"

Answer (score 0):

Change your statements as:

```
describe "as a student I want a working blog so people can post", js: true do
  it "should do something" do
  end
end
```

Note: js: true option is now in describe block.
Source: [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)